# Citrix: web fonts not loaded in Citrix browser

Tags: font-awesome, citrix, google-webfonts

We are developing an intranet website and we use Google fonts and Font Awesome the following way:

```
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/libs/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
```

People can access the intranet via Citrix from outside and Citrix has its browser (IE 11). It appears that fonts are loaded in the Citrix browser. If someone accesses the intranet directly inside the network, there is no issue. I am attaching an image showing the difference. The first navigation bar is the one with the issue. You can see that the home icon (Font Awesome) is missing and menu fonts (Google fonts) are not right.

[image]

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Hi, I've got the same issue. Did you have any luck finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Technically unrelated, but I managed to improve how fonts were displaying inside Chrome within Citrix by disabling this setting in Chrome.

Type this in your Chrome address bar and set to disable:

```
chrome://flags/#disable-accelerated-video-decode
```

ref: https://discussions.citrix.com/topic/390372-blurryfuzzy-display/?page=0#comment-1985489 (Comment on 20 June, final comment at time of adding this)